# 2 accounts under same email preventing me from loging in

Tags: password, account

A year ago I set up a WP account with email account A. I was unable to work with WP effectively.

I came back a year later with more knowledge & brought WP into a domain (*abc*) I already owned. I linked this second account to email A as well. I have made a website with *abc* using WP. After making the website, I decided to switch hosting providers from Go Daddy to Fat Cow. Somewhere in the process of switching the website from one provider to the next, my word press account got lost in cyberspace. I have attempted calling Go Daddy & Fat cow for support help, however they say I have to get ahold of WP support. Not only is my word press account gone, but also I somehow have to get my "SQL dump file" to Fat Cow. It may be obvious b/c of the language I'm using, but I am fairly new to this whole website design thing.

The second part to my problem, is that everytime I try to log into my new WP account that is linked to *abc*, it sayis I am using the incorrect password. I know i am using the correct password as I wrote down what it was. I got to the password reset link, & it has me enter my email so that it can send me an email with another password reset link. However, when I go to my email to find the password reset email from WP, I go to reset my password & it is directed to my first WP account that I built over a year ago. It's as though WP has deleted my *abc* account & is telliung me I ccan only access my account from a year ago. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the hosting provider Fat Cow gives you but if you have cPanel and phpMyAdmin, you can log into phpMyAdmin, find the database for your WordPress installation, and then find the `wp_users` table. Find one of the duplicates (2 entries with the same name) and delete one of them. Reset your password again and it should work.